# Mutlisafe pay integration with magento2 but i have an issue with second chance email

Tags: magento2.3, payment-gateway

I working with multi-safe pay but somehow multi-safe pay events do not fire second chance emails when someone has not completed payment for the order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue with the test account I have got the same issue on my past project.

Comment: Thank you. I check my account is test account I try in live it's fine there.